# Uploading and using static (for Django project) to AWS S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Thanks for taking the time to read this. My issue is simple.

I was able to setup the collectstatic function to upload static to AWS S3, but screwed up a little. I have been making some changes and now, my website is not using the correct url to load the css files. So my initial code moved the static to S3 bucket, folder 'static' and referenced it at this url:

```
https://{project}.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Now, after some of the changes I have made it references the same address, but without the 'static' folder:

```
https://{project}.amazonaws.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Same thing happens to collectstatic function. Instead of loading all the static to the 'static' folder it loads everything to the root of the bucket.

Here is my settings file:

**settings.py**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}


STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), ]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/static/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/media/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN)
```

Thanks for all the help in advance! I really appreciate the community and support.

Best,
Rasul Kireev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# constants

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
```

Override the s3boto3storage class variable location.

```
# custom_storages.py

from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

You can follow this [article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store files in static directory in bucket, then you need to override the Storage class.

Lets say you have a utilities module and inside that you have a `storages.py` file. Then the implementation should be like this:

```
# utilities/storages.py

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticRootS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
```

Then use it in settings:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'utilities.storages.StaticRootS3Boto3Storage'
```